# (ReactJs) Avoid rerendering on child input

Tags: reactjs

Recently I started going way more into design patterns and just reuse components instead of writing long lines of code.

As of the moment I am trying to reduce the forms length and created a "row" component.

```
 function FormRows({ x, w, z, Input1, Input2, Input3 }) {
        return (
            <div className={"row"}>
                <div className="col text-left">
                    <span style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>{x}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="col text-left">
                    {Input1}
                </div>
                <div className="col text-left">
                    <span style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>{w}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="col text-left">
                    {Input2 ? Input2 : ''}
                </div>
                <div className="col text-left">
                    <span style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>{z}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="col text-left">
                    {Input3}
                </div>
                <div className="col-2"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

then on the render I though calling it this way:

```
<FormRows
  x={'Visma Kortnamn'}
  w={'synas'}
  Input1={
    <Input
      placeholder={'Visma Kortnamn'}
      onChange={setVKortnamn}
    />
  }
  Input2={
    <Select
      onchange={setSynas}
      options={trueOrFalse.map((k, i) => {
       return (<option key={i} value={k}>{k}</option>)
      })}
    />
  }
/>
```

The problem is it is rerendering on every onChange event, thus not storing any value in State :s

Any tips how to fix this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention. The Input component is exported from another file and has the following code:

```
export function Input({ placeholder, onChange, defaultValue }) {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className="form-control form-control2 form-control-sm"
      onChange={onChange}
      style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Why don't you update the state on every onChange event?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy supposedly is doing that!

Comment: Am I missing the `onChange` method, or is it really missing from the snippets that you gave?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy no, they are there. The first snippet is a "design component" and tried to place the Input component inside the FormRows component. So the onChange should be on the Input component. However every time an event is fired, it serenaders the formRows component.